# Entity Framework Strings vs lambda... Missing .Execute

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using entity framework and I want to execute a query and would like to know which is the besr way to execute a query. Which is best practice and why, and which one is more per-formant.

Option 1)

```
        return
            this.Storage.Customer.OfType<Preferred>()
            .Include("Order")
            .Where("it.Id = @customerId AND it.CustomerType = @cusType", new ObjectParameter("customerId ", customerId), new ObjectParameter("cusType", (int)cusType))
            .Execute(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

OR

```
        return
        this.Storage.Customer.OfType<Preferred>()
        .Include(b  => b.Order)
        .Where(cust => cust.Id == customerId && cust.CustomerType== (int)cusType)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

The second question is why in option 2 us the .Execute not available? It appears red.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference *should* be negligible compared with the actual data access, but you need to *measure it* to determine for sure.

`Include` with a lambda just uses reflection to get the property name then calls the version with a string parameter, so the only overhead is parsing the expression.  (This is an implementation detail, however, so it is subject to change)

The benefit of using a lambda is type safety - using the wrong property name in a lambda will break the build, but using the wrong string will only fail at run-time.

The reason `Execute` is not available is because `Include` with a lambda parameter is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` that returns an `IQueryable<T>` in order to chain methods like `Where`.  `Include` with a string parameter is a method on `ObjectQuery<T>` that returns an `ObjectQuery<T>`.  `Execute` is a method on `ObjectQuery<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>` so it is not available when you use `IQueryable` methods.

Comment: Do you have an answer for .Execute?

Comment: what happens if you use the extension method then, in terms of using the execute you can control what happens to the current context, if you do not use the execute would you expect some different behavior? Some of our queries are using .Execute(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges)?

Comment: You could _try_ casting it to an `ObjectQuery<T>` to call `.Execute` but there may be another way to accomplish that with `IQueryable`.  That might me a good follow-up question :)